# How to create organization account that will be used to pay for Uber ride of app users?

Tags: android, ios, uber-api

**I am trying to integrate Uber REST API in my app. I want to create one organization account that will be used to pay for Uber ride of app users. Is there any way to do this?**

Comment: Uber is providing REST apis for fare calculation but user have to register with uber account it seems

Comment: this link may help [https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post]

Comment: @MidhunNarayan Can't we use one organization account for multiple user uber ride payment?

Comment: Why -ve rating to my question? Please explain

Comment: Because apparently you didn't read Stackoverflows FAQ on how to ask a question. [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Akaino Is it fine?

Comment: No, this will not work. There is not a way to pay for your own user's rides through the Uber Rides API currently. The users have to have their own accounts & payment methods.

Comment: @KyleDavis Thank you. You saved my RnD time :)